# IN main class can't call the sub class

Tags: java

```
import org.w3c.dom.ls.LSOutput;

public class Super {
    int x = 155;

    void display1() {
        System.out.println("values is " + x);
    }

    class Sub extends Super {
        int y = 587;

        void display2() {
            System.out.println("values was " + x);
            System.out.println("valus is. " + y);
        }

    }

}
```

***********main class**************

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Super ss = new Super();
        ss.display1();


        //how to call sub class. it is giving error : super is not an enclosed class
        Super.Sub rr = new Super.Sub();
        rr.display2();

    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You can't possibly expect a cohesive answer when you you've just dumped arbitrary code into the body of your question without described the problem at all.

Answer (score 2):

Replace

```
Super.Sub rr = new Super.Sub();
```

with

```
Super.Sub rr = new Super().new Sub();
```

or declare `Sub` as `static class`.

Check [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html) to learn more about it.